# MySQL - Joining 3 Tables and Make one row as a column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have tried to search for help on existing threads but I found myself at lost because of the answers.

Here's my scenario:

I have two tables: ACCOUNTS, NET_PROCEEDS

**ACCOUNTS** table has:

1. Account_ID
2. Account_Name
3. Account_Description

**NET_PROCEEDS** table has:

1. Net_Proceeds_ID
2. Account_ID
3. Fiscal_Year
4. Amount

Now my basic sql can join two tables with this output:

**Account_ID | Account_Name | Account_Description | Fiscal_Year | Amount**

But I am trying to come out with this output:

**Account_ID | Account_Name | Account_Description | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019**

The fiscal_year will become a column with a value of amount.

Any thoughts? I will appreciate your help. 
P.S I can't share the code, due to confidentiality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 ways to do it, depending on whether or not Account_ID is unique in both tables. 
The faster way (if Account_ID is unique to each table):

```
SELECT A.*, N16.Amount as Amount_2016 
, N17.Amount as Amount_2017 
, N18.Amount as Amount_2018 
, N19.Amount as Amount_2019 
FROM ACCOUNTS A 
LEFT JOIN NET_PROCEEDS N16 ON N16.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N16.Fiscal_Year = '2016'
LEFT JOIN NET_PROCEEDS N17 ON N17.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N17.Fiscal_Year = '2017'
LEFT JOIN NET_PROCEEDS N18 ON N18.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N18.Fiscal_Year = '2018'
LEFT JOIN NET_PROCEEDS N19 ON N19.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N19.Fiscal_Year = '2019'
```

The safer way (if Account_ID is not/may not be unique to each table):

```
SELECT A.*, (SELECT SUM(N16.Amount) FROM NET_PROCEEDS N16 ON N16.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N16.Fiscal_Year = '2016') as Amount_2016 
, (SELECT SUM(N17.Amount) FROM NET_PROCEEDS N17 ON N17.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N17.Fiscal_Year = '2017') as Amount_2017
, (SELECT SUM(N18.Amount) FROM NET_PROCEEDS N18 ON N18.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N18.Fiscal_Year = '2018') as Amount_2018 
, (SELECT SUM(N19.Amount) FROM NET_PROCEEDS N19 ON N19.Account_ID = A.Account_ID AND N19.Fiscal_Year = '2019') as Amount_2019 
FROM ACCOUNTS A
```

If you use the first one when Account_ID is not unique it will create multiple rows for each duplicate instance of Account_ID which will mess with any SUMs or COUNTs etc.

Comment: Thanks for this but there could be many account_ID in net_proceeds table.

Comment: Hi, yea that's why you'd use the second query